# JQuery Datatable Error “Cannot read property length of undefined jquery.dataTables.min.js:45

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am making an AJAX call to retrieve data, and get back the data in JSON format. However I am getting an error and nothing gets returned to the datatable.  The data gets returned in this format:

```
[
{
    "part_number": "630000311",
    "qty": "1",
    "description": "PUMP, ACE PRODUCT 04 & OLDER",
    "point": "1",
    "cost": "535.23",
    "vendor_name": "Ace Pump Corporation",
    "total_sold": "5"
},
{
    "part_number": "400200179",
    "qty": "0",
    "description": "SEAL, DOOR CAB",
    "point": "2",
    "cost": "21.32",
    "vendor_name": "Angus-Palm Greeneville Inc",
    "total_sold": "44"
}
]
```

Here is my Jquery:

```
             $('#partTable').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "searching": false,
            "responsive": true,
            "ajax": { "async": "false", "url": "/vvvv/vvvWS.php", "type": "GET", "data": function (c) { c.locations = locations; c.percentages = percentages; } },
            "columns": [{"data": "part_number", "data": "qty", "data": "description", "data": "point", "data": "cost", "data": "vendor_name", "data": "total_sold"}]
        });
```

Comment: The value of your `"columns"` property doesn't make much sense. It's equivalent to `[{"data": "total_sold"}]` though this may be unrelated to the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles across this, I solved this with the formatting of the JSON data, here is the new format:

```
{
"data":
[
{
"part_number": "630000311",
"qty": "1",
"description": "PUMP, ACE PRODUCT 04 & OLDER",
"point": "1",
"cost": "535.23",
"vendor_name": "Ace Pump Corporation",
"total_sold": "5"
},
{
"part_number": "400200179",
"qty": "0",
"description": "SEAL, DOOR CAB",
"point": "2",
"cost": "21.32",
"vendor_name": "Angus-Palm Greeneville Inc",
"total_sold": "44"
}
]
}
```